# How can I use one Graylog stream inside another?

Tags: graylog2

I have some servers logging a whole lot of stuff, including some FTP information that I extract to one stream in Graylog.

I have some other servers that log a bunch of information that relates to the FTP log, but are not FTP log. I extract those to a stream also.

What I would like to do, is combine the two streams into one, so that I can observe how the FTP servers affect what goes on on the other servers. I cannot simply combine the two into one stream directly because I must have the FTP facility **only** from the FTP servers and **everything** from the others.

I have tried creating a third stream with inputs matching ("exactly streams FTP SERVERS" *or* "exactly streams OTHER SERVERS") but that stream remains empty.